# How can i execute a function after a form submission causes a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am using shopify's built in customer create, login, reset form submissions which on submit, forces the page to refresh. My intention is to show a message that shows after the page has been refreshed via a button click function. This is what i have so far; The message shows until that page refreshes and then the active class is removed as you would expect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  class Alert {
    constructor() {
      this.customerAlert = document.createElement('div');
    }
    init(){
      this.customerAlert.classList.add('customer-alert');
      document.querySelector('body').append(this.customerAlert);
    }
    show(message){
      this.customerAlert.textContent = message;
        this.customerAlert.classList.add('active');
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.customerAlert.classList.remove('active');
      }, 8000);
    }
  }

  //create snackbar and initiate
  const alertMessage = new Alert();
  alertMessage.init();

  const createAccountButton = document.querySelector('input.account-trigger');

  createAccountButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alertMessage.show('Your account in now under review');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean variable in session storage just prior to the submit to represent the two states, and then read it in after the refresh.

Something like this:

```
function HandleFlag(){

var F=sessionStorage.getItem('Flag');

if(F=='1'){

 // display your message box here

 sessionStorage.setItem('Flag','0');

} else {

 // the state is "0" so toggle it just before submitting

   sessionStorage.setItem('Flag','1');
 }

}
```

I hope you get my drift.